# How to add a custom constraint to a vaadin-text-field

Tags: vaadin

We want to add our own validation/contraints to a Vaadin field in the client side web components library. What should be the correct way to achieve this? I think it should be done by adding a constraint to the "constraints" property of the field, but there doesn't seem to be an official API for this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `vaadin-text-field` in Lit-template in Flow project? Or are you using it in Hilla project? If the latter is it React or Lit based? Is this standalone constraint or something linked to entity constraints (JSR-303)?

Comment: We are using vaadin-text-field standalone (our own GraphQL server) in a lit project, no entity constraints or anything. We want to add our own custom client side validations to the field and have implemented this by using the "error-message" and "invalid" property of the field.

Issue is that the field itself updates it's "invalid" property when it for example is required and has a value.

It would be nice when the fields have an API to add custom constraints so this is nicely integrated in the lifecycle of the field. Or is this already possible?

Answer (score 2):

If a field does not have explicitly added features for the validation
you are looking for (e.g. date pickers allow to restrict min/max dates,
text fields allow for a regexp, ...), then the generic approach is to
validate in the binder.

> ```java
> binder.forField(emailField)
>     // Explicit validator instance
>     .withValidator(new EmailValidator("This doesn't look like a valid email address"))
>     .bind(Person::getEmail, Person::setEmail);
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Source: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder-validation

Or in other words: there is no generic way to add generic validation to
any field.  If you have to do that often, create a `CustomField`, that
uses a `Binder` to bind to a wrapped field and allow for
validation/conversion there.

Comment: sorry, I meant in the Vaadin web components, not the server side framework.

Comment: @DanielvanMil I leave the answer open until you clarify your question, so others won't miss this (seeing deleted answers takes some amount of rep here)

Answer (score 0):

The architecture in Vaadin's both frameworks Flow (Java) and Hilla (Typescript) is based on idea, that complex validation happens using utility class, which in case of Flow is Binder as mentioned in the other answer and Hilla has its own Binder too, but it is not available as standalone dependency.

The component `vaadin-text-field` has some options for rudimentary constraint handling, e.g. if you want to restrict the field to allow only phone numbers of certain format, you can use properties, `min-length`, `max-length`, `pattern` and `allowed-char-pattern` like this:

```
<vaadin-text-field
  required
  min-length="5"
  max-length="18"
  pattern="^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-s.]?[0-9]{3}[-s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$"
  allowed-char-pattern="[0-9()+-]"
  label="Phone number"
  helper-text="Format: +(123)456-7890"
></vaadin-text-field>
```

Another option is just to listen value change and check the value upon change event.

```
field.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if (!(field.value === 'Tatu')) {
      field.invalid = true;
      field.errorMessage = 'Input Tatu'
    } else { 
      field.invalid = false;
       field.errorMessage = undefined
    }
});
```